# Query by field name in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, select, find, cakephp-1.3

Hello I have a very simple question, how do we query by field name?? I am using the regular query method, but I want to learn how it is done by one of the cakePHP methods, which would look like `$this->Model->find('/*something like a query*/').`

I am presently using the query method like `$this->Model->query('select field_name from table_name');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this->Model->find('all', array('fields' => array('field_name')));
```

You can find more on retrieving your data in the [Cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1017/Retrieving-Your-Data).